# How do I handle my routing for angular dynamic site

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel-4

I am new to angular, and I have a content managed and all I want angular for is to handle the routes and show content.

So I want one route; some thing like .when('/{any?}')

And my backend  (laravel) will handle all processing and just send back the content. I dont want to have to pre define my routes.

However because that route covers pretty much anything, it doesn't reload any content.

does anyone have any ideas as to the best approach?

Comment: What you're searching for is the [otherwise method](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$routeProvider).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to define other routes, You can use "otherwise" command, like Florian was recommended:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute'])
.config(
  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .otherwise({ 
      templateUrl : 'ng-home', 
      controller : 'homeController'
      });
  });

app.controller('homeController', function($scope){
});
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple like that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Do you make a single test on jsfiddle or plunk? I'm understand your question, but I need a code to help you on your question.

Comment: var prevPath;
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute']).config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    

    $routeProvider.when('/{:any?}',{
        templateUrl : 'ng-home',
        controller : 'homeController',
    });

});




app.controller('homeController', function($scope){

})

Comment: essentially, I want angular to send the path to laravel, which will then look up the url.